# Parse ALM XML data with Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Any ideas on parsing the following - I'm getting stuck on parse by tagname as they are all the same. I just want to get each value.

```
<Entities TotalResults="3">
    <Entity Type="defect">
        <Fields>
            <Field Name="id">
                <Value>2</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="project">
                <Value>P10</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="name">
                <Value>MMW - Issue with Referral check upon deployment of pre-assembly test</Value>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
        <RelatedEntities/>
    </Entity>
    <Entity Type="defect">
        <Fields>
            <Field Name="id">
                <Value>777</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="project">
                <Value>P10</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="name">
                <Value>R6 throwing CORBA transaction error on product set-up screen on every bundle selection</Value>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
        <RelatedEntities/>
    </Entity>
```

Code I'm trying is below - 
        File fXmlFile = new File("D:/Java/file.xml");

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Entity");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            System.out.println("Name : " + eElement.getAttribute("Field"));
```

Comment: It would help if you could show the code you've already written.

Comment: see this tutorial it help you to parse XML data  https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Answer (score 0):

```
Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
System.out.println("Defect ID    : " + Element.getElementsByTagName("Value").item(0).getTextContent());
System.out.println("Project      : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Value").item(1).getTextContent());
 System.out.println("Description  : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Value").item(2).getTextContent());
```